# How to change the laravel config file reference env file to database settings

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How to change the laravel config file reference env to database settings.

**Example:**
**laravel\config\captcha.php**

```
return [
    'secret' => env('CAPTCHA_SECRET', 'default_secret'),
    'sitekey' => env('CAPTCHA_SITEKEY', 'default_sitekey')
];
```

Instead of env function i want to use eloquent model Settings::where('key','CAPTCHA_SECRET')->first()->value()

Answer (score 2):

You can set config values like this in `AppServiceProvider::boot()`:

```
$secret = Settings::where('key', 'CAPTCHA_SECRET')->first()->value();
config(['captcha.secret' => $secret]);
```